# SQL- top five sold products to different categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three sql tables

```
Orders:       Clients:   Products:
id            id         id
product_id    gender     category_name
client_id     city
```

and i need to output top 5 product_id's for each category_name grouped by gender and city. For example

```
category1  category1  category1  category1
male       female     male       female 
city1      city1      city2      city2
top5       top5       top5       top5

category2  category2  category2  category2
male       female     male       female 
city1      city1      city2      city2
top5       top5       top5       top5
........................................
etc.
```

How do i get that? Do i need to left join clients and products to orders, then group by category, gender and city and finally apply sorting and limit to 5?

Comment: Go and check with the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: @DineshDB your example doesn't involve counting of repeated products. E.g.
product_name   num_purchases
toothbrush         967

Comment: @Barmar i need to count those things not just filter them

Comment: @Superbman Use one of the techniques in that answer on the result of a query that uses `COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: well, that didn't help much :/

Comment: @Superbman I tried something. Check it out [Trial Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a445b/7)

Comment: @cdaiga looks great, that's almost what i want. Is it possible to add how many times those products were purchased?

Comment: @cdaiga After reading some of the suggested questions, I tried and wrote this query but it returned incorrect information :( https://pastebin.com/1NdQZemP